# Converting from char to int in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Consider:

```
int a = Convert.ToChar(textBox3.Text);
```

The textbox contains a string of elements like *abcd*. From the above syntax I am not able to convert the entire string of elements and the error is like string must be exactly one character long. Whereas if the textbox is having only one element it is working fine.

Comment: So what you are expecting in int variable `a` if the `textBox3.Text` is `abcd`

Comment: @un-lucky. The corresponding ascii values.

Comment: @Manukumar but then you need a int array, not a single int (actually, a byte array should be more concise in this case)

Comment: Then please help me to find the syntax to convert the entire string .

Comment: See the duplicate question. It is `byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox3.Text);`

Comment: @Guilherme .its not exactly to convert into ascii values. Its like the controller is sending a 4byte character and i want to convert to integer.

Comment: @Manukumar please be more clear. Edit your question (or ask a new one) and put some examples of input and the expected output, so we can help you better.